# Why does my css drop down menu get cut off at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8frfH/2/

Like the title says, why does the drop down menu get cut off? Is it because of a mix of different positions, or because of the content/divs under the menu? This happens when you try to use the list items in the dropdown menu, in Chrome/FF/IE.

HTML

```
    <body>
        <h1 id="site_title">Frontrunners</h1>
        <div id="main">

            <div id="wrapper"> <!-- DENNE GÅR RUNDT HELE HEADER. UNØDVENDIG IFT. <HEADER>? -->
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vilDvFB.jpg" alt="Bakgrundsbilde">
                <header>
                </header>                   

                <nav id="meny" role="navigation">

                    <ul>
                        <li id="hjem"><a href="index.php?&amp;title=Frontrunners%20-%20Training%20program%20for%20everyone">Hjem</a></li>

                        <li id="maraton">Maraton

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php?page=2&amp;title=Introduksjon%20til%20programmet">Introduksjon</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?page=3&amp;title=Reglene%20for%20FIRST-programmet">Reglene</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?page=4&amp;title=Treningsprogrammet%20for%20%20ditt%20første%20maraton">Treningsprogram</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>

                        <li id="filosofier">Filosofier
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php?page=5&amp;title=Tempotrening%20kontra%20Pulstrening">Tempo vs Puls</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?page=6&amp;title=Generelt%20om%20kosthold%20fra%20Olympiatoppen">Råd fra Olympiatoppen</a></li>
                            </ul>                  
                        </li>

                        <li id="utstyr">Utstyr

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php?page=7&amp;title=Minimalisme%20-%20Bare%20foot%20running">Minimalisme</a></li>
                                <li>Utstyr 2</li>
                                <li>Utstyr 3</li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li id="om">Om
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php?page=8&amp;title=Frontrunners%20-%20Kontakt%20oss">Kontakt oss</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </div>

            <div id="wrapperinnhold">

            <div id="innhold"> <!-- MULIG WRAPPER FOR ALT INNHOLD UTENOM HEADER OG FOOTER -->

<div id="kolonne1">
</div>
<div id="kolonne2">

<article>

    <h2>Idéen</h2>
    <p>
        Alle som driver med sport ønsker å gjøre det best mulig. Kanskje man ikke føler seg drevet av denne tanken, men kan man gjøre noen endringer i teknikk, utstyr, treningsrutiner eller på andre måter endre det man har gjort, uten at det koster for mye, så velger mange å prøve det.

        Denne websiden har tatt som mål av seg å presentere en del aspekter ved trening, kosthold og tilhørende emner som kan være interessante for dem som ønsker å få noen nye ideer og inputs i forhold til sin egen trening.</p>

    <p>
        Vi har tatt utgangspunkt i FIRST maratonprogrammet, samt funnet frem en del kalkulatorer og verktøy for å sitt anbefalte treningstempo, treningssoner og konvertering av miles til kilometer blant annet.</p>
    <h2>Hvordan bruke siden</h2>
    <p>
        Vi har i tillegg til å presentere tekst og informasjon vedrørende trening og omliggende temaer valgt å gi deg som besøkende en rekke verktøy for å hjelpe å beregne paramterene for nettopp deg, slik at du også kan følge disse planene og programmene for en       mer effektiv og god trening frem mot maraton.
    </p>

    </article>

    </div>         
    <div id="kolonne3">

    </div>  

    <div id="aside_right_wrapper">

    <div id="aside_sitat_wrapper">
        <?php
        include './php/quoteGenerator.php';
        getRandomQuote();
        ?>
    </div>


    <div id="aside_forslag">
        <?php
        include "./php/newsGenerator.php";
        getRandomArticlePreviews();
        ?>
    </div>

    </div>





    <footer role="contentinfo">
    <!--<img src="./img/footer.png" alt="Footer-bilde av en løpende dame">-->
    </footer>
    </div> <!-- WRAPPER INNHOLD -->
    </div>  
    </div>  <!--MULIGENS DIV KOLONNER -->
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px){

body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    }

    #site_title{
        /*Denne er for å sette en skjult h1 for WCAG validering*/
        display: none;
    }

    #main {
        background-image:url('../img/footer.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: bottom;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #main_kalk {
        width: 100%;
        background-image:url('../img/footer_kalk.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%, 40%;
        background-position: bottom, left;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #wrapperinnhold {
        background-image:url('../img/graphics.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 40%;
        /*Kommenterer følgende på grunn av valideringsfeil (Lukas)*/
        background-position: top left;
    }

    #innhold {
        padding-top: 2%;
        margin-left: 7%;
    }

    #mobile{
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }


    p{
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }


    h2{
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: #186000;
        background-image: url('../img/h1tag.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        height: 80px;
    }


    #aside_forslag h2{
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }


    #kolonner {

    }

    #kolonne1 {
        width: 160px;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
        /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
        /*background-color: #B2E6FF;*/
        position: relative;

    }
    #kolonne2 {

        width: 470px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
        float: left;
        /*background-color: #B2E6FF;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    #kolonne3 {   
        width: 290px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
        float: right;
        /*background-color: white;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    /* VERKTØYMENY START */

    #toolsslide{
        /*    min-height: 200px;
            width: 180px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 330px;
            left: -178px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #7D5D46;
            color: white;
            background-color: white;
            opacity: 0.8;
            border-right-style: solid;
            border-top-style: solid;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            padding-left: 5px;*/

    }
    #gjennomsiktigmeny{
        min-height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 330px;
        left: -178px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #7D5D46;
        color: white;
        /*background-color: white;*/
        opacity: 0.8;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #888888;
    }

    #table_tools_div{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #table_tools{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #table_tools tr{
        height: 23px;
    }

    #table_tools_header{
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #table_tools a{
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #table_tools_V{
        /*Definerer den første bokstaven i side tool menyen*/
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .table_tools_standard{
        /*Definerer alle andre bokstaver på side menyen*/
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .menutools:hover {
        background: #654C39;
    }

    .menutools {
        width: 180px;
    }

    /* VERKTØYMENY SLUTT */

    footer {
        z-index: -1;
        /*background-image:url('../img/footer.png');*/
        height: 482px;
        clear: both;
    }
    #wrapper {
        /*        background-image: url('../img/blogrunningprog2.jpg');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: 100% 100%;*/
        position: relative;
        /*        width: 100%;
                height: 400px;*/
        /*top: 0; KOMMENTERT UT
        left: 0; KOMMENTERT UT*/ 
        margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
        width: 100%;
        /*min-width: 99%; KOMMENTERT UT */

    }

    #wrapper img{
        /*position: relative; KOMMENTERT UT*/
        width: 100%;
    }

    header {
        position: relative; /* ENDRET TIL RELATIVE FRA ABSOLUTE */
        top: 0;
    }

    nav {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
    } 

    #gjennomsiktigmeny a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #meny {
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-weight: lighter;
    }   

    #meny a{
        font-weight: lighter;
    }

    #meny ul {
        /*display: inline-block;*/
        margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;

    }

    #meny li {
        display: inline-block;
        /*background: #FFF;*/
        /*width: 20%; */
        padding: 3px 70px 0px 30px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        /*text-align: center;*/

        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    #meny ul li a:link {
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    #meny ul li a:visited {
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #meny ul li:hover {
        /*color: #fff;*/

    }

    #meny ul li ul {
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;

        width: 150px;
        left: 0;
        top: 33px;

        -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }

    #meny ul li ul li { 
        margin-left: 0px;
        background: #7D5D46; 
        /*display: block; */
        color: #fff;
        width: 150px;
        /*text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;*/
        font-weight: normal;
        clear: both;
    }

    #meny ul li ul li:hover { 
        background: #654C39; 
    }

    #meny ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #headerbottom {

    }

    .vertlinjeh {
        border-color: #D7D7D7;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .vertlinjev {
        border-color: #D7D7D7;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .horilinje {
        border-color: #D7D7D7;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
    /*#bakgrunn_hoyre{

    }*/


    /*Konfigurasjon av aside elementer til høyre*/
    #aside_right_wrapper{
        /*Wraper for alle elementer som er plasert til høyre.*/
        float: left;
        margin-left: 40px;
        width: 260px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    #aside_sitat_wrapper{
        /*Wrapper for all som har med sitat å gjøre*/
        width: 260px;
        height: 100px;
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        background-image: url('../img/quote_sign2.gif');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left top;
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    #div_quote{
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #666666;
    }

    #div_quote_author{
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-style: italic;
        text-align: right;
        color: #186000;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    #aside_forslag{
        /*Her ligger alle artikkelforslag*/
    }
    .aside_art_prev_header h3{
        font-size: 17px;
        color: #009933;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .aside_art_prev_prgf{
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        text-align: justify;
        color: #333333;
    }
    .aside_art_prev_link{
        font-size: 12px;
        float: right;
    }

    /*Slutt på konfigurasjon av aside elementer*/
}
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Doesn't seem cut off to me

Comment: Same for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: Tested on Chrome, FF, and IE10; No problems seen.

Comment: When you try to use the list items in the drop down ul it will cut off. That is what I am experiencing. This happens in Chrome, FF and IE.

Comment: Define cut off please. The menus are showing but you can't hover on them, as soon as you try to hover the sub menus, the dropdown is gone. Unless you hover really fast and from certain angles

Answer (score 1):

See solution fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8frfH/15/

By "cut off", if you mean the sub menu hides when you try to hover it, it's because there is a space between the main UL and the sub UL, e.g. Maraton -> Introduksjon. Since the inner UL is positioned absolutely, the parent's (LI) box doesn't extend over it, so when you move your mouse, it essentially loses :hover.

Try this, adjust the top of the inner UL to make it touch the LI

```
#meny ul li ul {
   ...
   ...
   top: 25px;
}
```

If you don't want to move the UL, you can add a padding to the UL to make it's box 'larger' by a few pixels:

```
#meny li {
    ...
    ...
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Also don't forget to add a z-index to the inner UL so that it goes over your main content.

Comment: Should I do anything with the inner ULs positioning? I've done all the other things you have suggested, but it still disappears when it reaches <div id="innhold">.

Comment: Seems to be working now, altough I had to move the ul further up into the picture, so it's not as centered as before.